# Parent Activity is recreating after calling Camera intent in Android Oreo

Tags: android, android-camera-intent, android-8.0-oreo

I am using Media intent capturing image. Once process completed result will be send back to parent.
Above mentioned process working properly up to Nougat Os but in Oreo the parent activity is recreating again. How can i solve this issue.

Answer (score 3):

> Above mentioned process working properly up to Nougat Os but in Oreo the parent activity is recreating again

Your process is being terminated while the camera app is in the foreground. This is perfectly normal and has nothing to do with Android 8.0. It has everything to do with the available system RAM and what is all going on in the device at the time.

> How can i solve this issue.

There is no issue. Your process can be terminated at any point when you do not have the foreground UI. Your code needs to deal with that.

For example, if you are using `EXTRA_OUTPUT` on your `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`, you need to remember that value, as you do not get it back in any form of result from the camera app. Saving it in the saved instance state `Bundle` is a typical solution, as I illustrate in [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Camera/FileProvider), particularly in this activity:

```
/***
 Copyright (c) 2008-2017 CommonsWare, LLC
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
 of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
 by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
 License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
 OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
 language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

 Covered in detail in the book _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
 https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.camcon;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private static final String EXTRA_FILENAME=
    "com.commonsware.android.camcon.EXTRA_FILENAME";
  private static final String FILENAME="CameraContentDemo.jpeg";
  private static final int CONTENT_REQUEST=1337;
  private static final String AUTHORITY=
    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+".provider";
  private static final String PHOTOS="photos";
  private File output=null;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState==null) {
      output=new File(new File(getFilesDir(), PHOTOS), FILENAME);

      if (output.exists()) {
        output.delete();
      }
      else {
        output.getParentFile().mkdirs();
      }

      Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
      Uri outputUri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITY, output);

      i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputUri);

      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
      }
      else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        ClipData clip=
          ClipData.newUri(getContentResolver(), "A photo", outputUri);

        i.setClipData(clip);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
      }
      else {
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList=
          getPackageManager()
            .queryIntentActivities(i, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
          String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
          grantUriPermission(packageName, outputUri,
            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        }
      }

      try {
        startActivityForResult(i, CONTENT_REQUEST);
      }
      catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.msg_no_camera, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
      }
    }
    else {
      output=(File)savedInstanceState.getSerializable(EXTRA_FILENAME);
    }
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putSerializable(EXTRA_FILENAME, output);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                  Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CONTENT_REQUEST) {
      if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Intent i=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri outputUri=FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITY, output);

        i.setDataAndType(outputUri, "image/jpeg");
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

        try {
          startActivity(i);
        }
        catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
          Toast.makeText(this, R.string.msg_no_viewer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        finish();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here, I hold onto the `output` location in the saved instance state `Bundle`, so even if my process is terminated, I will get my `output` back.

Comment: I modified the code as you mentioned above. Now i am able to handle my issue. Thank you very much @Commonsware.